# What is an implementation of the table HTML element in GWT?

Tags: html, gwt

There are implementations of HTML elements by GWT components, e.g.

`<div>` - FlowPanel

`<fieldset>` - CaptionPanel

`<a>` - Anchor

What is an implementation of the `<table>` HTML element in GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `FlexTable`, `Grid` and `CellTable`, depending on your use-case.

Or you could just use an `HTMLPanel` and put a `<table>` inside: as a rule of thumb, don't use a widget if you could just use HTML in an `HTMLPanel` (this is assuming you're using UiBinder to code your `HTMLPanel`'s content)